# Chopin Etude Op. 10, No. 3, m. 41—left-hand note at the end of the chromatic sequence: F sharp or G?

Tags: piano, sheet-music, chopin

Most editions I've found (including the [first edition](https://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ReverseLookup/423660)) have an F#, but others follow the same descending pattern up to that point and print a G.

Can anybody shed some light on which note is correct? Or which is commonly played?

I haven't been able to find an Urtext or manuscript version but if anyone from The Morgan Library is reading, there is an [autograph manuscript](https://www.themorgan.org/music-manuscripts-and-printed-music/114339) in your collection

F#:

[image: Schlessinger, 1833]
[image: Rudorff, 1880]

G:

[image: Cortot, 1915]
[image: Schirmer, 1916]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Henle urtext<sup>1</sup> gives f♯ and includes no commentary on this pitch — that is, Henle seems to feel there is no question surrounding that note.

[image: Chopin 10/3 m. 41, Henle urtext edition]

The manuscript versions<sup>2</sup> also give f♯

[image: Chopin 10/3 m. 41, manuscript]

In addition, f♯ makes harmonic sense — it's the root of an f♯7 chord, which reinforces the cadence on b major on the downbeat of the following measure.

---

<sup>1</sup> Chopin, *Etudes* op. 10 (G. Henle Verlag, n.d. [1983?]).

<sup>2</sup> [Chopin Variorum Edition](https://chopinonline.ac.uk/ocve/browse/barview?workid=6339&pageimageid=79223&barid=41). The link is to a list of all copies of m. 41.